# Isaiah 53:12; Romans 8:27, what is the criterion of sainthood?

Tags: romans, isaiah

Isaiah 53:12 (KJV):

> ...and made intercession for the transgressors.

Romans 8:27 (KJV):

> ...he maketh intercession for the saints according to {the will of} God.

1 John 2:1 (KJV):

> ...And if any man sin, we have an advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous:

From the above mentioned verses, what is the criterion of sainthood?

Could a man be a saint and a sinner in the same time?

If so, could the Son of God intercede and advocate for the non saintly  sinners?

Could we consider the non saintly as non godly?

Comment: @NigelJ thank you Nigel, I modified the question to fit the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operative word (adjective) here is ἅγιος (hagios) and is plural in Rom 8:27 and is translated "saints".  Other versions give "Gods People" (NIV, GWT, Weymouth), "believers" (NLT).

In W E Vine, "Expository Dictionary of NT Words", we find this entry under "Saint(s)",

> In the plural, as used of believers, it designates all such and is not
>   applied merely to persons of exceptional holiness … See 1 Thess 1:10,
>   where "His saints" are also described as "them that believed", ie, the
>   whole number of the redeemed.  They are called "holy ones" in Jude 14.

BDAG offers this meaning for such verses, "believers, loyal followers, saints, of Christians as consecrated to God", eg, Acts 9:13, 32, Rom 1:7, 8:27, 12:13, 15:25, 1 Cor 1:2, 6:1, 2 Cor 1:1, Eph 2:19, 3:8, Phil 4:22, Col 1:4, 1 Tim 5:10, Heb 6:10, etc.

Note that "saints" are not sinlessly perfect.  This can be see in the first letter to the Corinthians which is addressed to the "saints" and yet 1 Cor 5 and 6 Paul rebukes them for their failings!

Similarly, Paul's letter to the Romans is also addressed to "saints" (1:7), yet in Rom 3:10-18 he says repeatedly that there is no one righteous, not one!

Therefore, a "saint" in the Biblical sense is a sinner (a human) who has decided to believe in Christ and follow Him.  Such an action does NOT make the person instantly perfect - that is a lifelong process that will be miraculously completed when we are glorified (1 Cor 15:51-54).

I found this neat summary on this web site: https://www.gotquestions.org/sinners-saints.html

> We are not saints because we have been declared to be saints by a
>   church, nor can we work our way to sainthood. Once we are saved by
>   faith, however, we are called to certain actions befitting our calling
>   as saints of God. “But just as he who called you is holy, so be holy
>   in all you do; for it is written: ‘Be holy, because I am holy’” (1
>   Peter 1:15–16). Saints are not sinless, but the lives of saints do
>   reflect the reality of the presence of Christ in our hearts, in whom
>   we “live and move and have our being” (Acts 17:28).

Answer (score 1):

The English word "saintly" you use hearkens to the general, worldly concept of 
"saints" as being "good" people. Never harming others, but always helping them. Self-sacrificing. Religious. The Bible, I believe, never uses the word "saintly" of nonbelievers. One is either a saint, or one isn't. Meaning one is either chosen by God, or one isn't ('yet'), as proven by one's faith.

**Without faith it is impossible to be well pleasing to Him, for he who comes forward to God must believe that He is and that He is a rewarder of those who diligently seek Him.** Heb 11:6. **Come forward to the Holy of Holies with a true heart in full assurance of faith, having our hearts sprinkled from an evil conscience.** 10:22.

The Bible's emphasis is on God. God's mercy. God saving us. Not on what we can do. As in a parable Jesus gave. (In fact His name "Jesus" means "Jehovah the Savior" or "the salvation of Jehovah.") **Behold, a certain lawyer stood up and put Him to the test, saying, Teacher, what should I do to inherit eternal life? And He said to him, What is written in the law? How do you read it? And he answered and said, "You shall love the Lord your God from your whole heart and with your whole soul and with your whole strength and with your whole mind, and your neighbor as yourself." And He said to him, You have answered correctly; do this, and you shall have life. But he, wanting to justify himself, said to Jesus, And who is my neighbor? Jesus, taking up the question, said, A certain man was going down from Jerusalem to Jericho, and he fell among robbers, who having both stripped him and beaten him, went away, leaving him half dead. And by coincidence a certain priest was going down on that road; and when he saw him, he passed by on the opposite side. And likewise also a Levite, when he came to the place and saw him, passed by on the opposite side. But a certain Samaritan, who was journeying, came upon him; and when he saw him, he was moved with compassion; 
and he came to him and bound up his wounds and poured oil and wine on them. And placing him on his own beast, he brought him to an inn and took care of him. 
And on the next day he took out two denarii and gave them to the innkeeper and said, Take care of him; and whatever you spend in addition to this, when I return, I will repay you. Which of these three, does it seem to you, has become a neighbor to him who fell into the hands of the robbers? And he said, The one who showed mercy to him. And Jesus said to him, Go, and you do likewise.** Lk 10:25-37.

We readers often twist this story into an instruction to be the good Samaritan. But Jesus is the good Samaritan. Who had mercy on us--helpless sinners. (Yes, in fact to make us parts of His Body.)

On the cross, Jesus Christ (God Jehovah incarnate), as Isa 53:12 says, interceded for the transgressors. **And Jesus said, Father, forgive them, for they do not know what they are doing. And dividing His garments, they cast lots.** Lk 23:34.

Thus the criterion for sainthood, Salah, is to come forward to God through Jesus Christ for the forgiveness of your sins. **He is able to save to the uttermost those who come forward to God through Him, since He lives always to intercede for them.** Heb 7:25. **Thomas said to Him, Lord, we do not know where You are going; how can we know the way? Jesus said to him, I am the way and the reality and the life; no one comes to the Father except through Me.** Jn 14:5-6. **Therefore let it be known to you, men, brothers, that through this One forgiveness of sins is announced to you; 
and from all the things from which you were not able to be justified by the law of Moses, in this One everyone who believes is justified.** Ac 10:38-39.

Answer (score 0):

> *1 Peter* 2.9-12 (ESV) 9 But you are a chosen race, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, a people for his own possession, that you may proclaim the excellencies of him who called you out of darkness into his marvelous light. 10 Once you were not a people, but now you are God's people; once you had not received mercy, but now you have received mercy.
>
> 11 Beloved, I urge you as sojourners and exiles to abstain from the passions of the flesh, which wage war against your soul. 12 Keep your conduct among the Gentiles honorable, so that when they speak against you as evildoers, they may see your good deeds and glorify God on the day of visitation.

The psalm and *Romans* both use the word intercession, but in different contexts. Jesus interceded for the saints to take away the judgment against sin, thus sanctifying them. The Holy Spirit intercedes for the saints in day-to-day issues, according to their needs.

Peter tells the believers that they are a holy nation, which I believe qualifies them as saints, people set apart to God. At the same time, he tells them to abstain from the passions of the flesh. He says this because they are not fully compliant, that is, they are still sinning to some extent.

1. Everyone is a sinner; through grace and faith, some of us are saved
2. I can speak from my own experience that Jesus interceded numerous times while I was a heathen, and that led to my salvation
3. Jesus is the standard for godliness, and I haven't met anyone who has attained that goal